# php fopen fails to open a file for writing in Mac OS X

Tags: php, apache, macos, file-permissions, fopen

I'm running php script updreading.php locally on my laptop (with Mac OS X 10.6.7).
Here's the contents of updreading.php

```
<?php
    $outFile = "examples-output.txt";
    $out = fopen($outFile, 'w') or die("can't open write file");
?>
```

When I run it, I get "can't open write file" error message. I think it should have something to do with permissions. I've made myself (arman) an owner of /Library/WebServer/Documents/ with Read&Write permissions and 'applied settings to enclosed items'. My script and file I'm writing to (examples-output.txt) is located in /Library/WebServer/Documents/wabun/. Here are the permissions for files in /Library/WebServer/Documents/wabun/:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 arman  admin         0 May  1 01:03 examples-output.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 arman  staff      1657 May  1 01:04 updreading.php
```

I was trying to resolve the issue for the last 4 hours trying different permissions without luck. Any ideas how to resolve this issue, guys? Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump(is_writable($outFile));`?

Comment: @Charles: Unnecessary question, must be false...

Comment: @Alix, it'll be false only if the world isn't insane.  I've seen PHP fail to open files for writing, yet return true when you ask it if the file is writable.  It ended up being some bizarre SELinux issue, though this particular question is about OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the issue is that your webserver or PHP instance is not running under the same user (`arman`), you can check this using the [`get_current_user()`](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php) function. You can either configure apache to run with your privileges (ask in ServerFault) or give the folder more generous permissions, like `0777`.

Another thing, are you sure `$outFile` maps to an *absolute* path? Try doing:

```
var_dump(is_file($outfile));
```

Answer (score 8):

I was having this exact same problem. I had to make sure the permissions were correct for all of the *parent* folders as well. For instance, if (in OSX) trying to write to the directory 
`~/foo/bar/baz`, I solved it with the command `chmod -R 777 ~/foo`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make apache (assuming apache is server you are using) the owner or put in group (and give group write access) or give write access to all or etc.. IOW apache is the one actually executing the script, not you.

Comment: Can you test & explain how to do this _"you need to make apache (assuming apache is server you are using) the owner or put in group (and give group write access)"_ that would be very helpful!

Comment: `chmod` to change read/write/exec perms of file, `chown` to change owner of file, and `chgrp` to change group of file. The *easiest* (and least secure) fix would be to `chmod 777 [target file/dir]` all files in question.  This will give read/write/exec perms to all owners/groups. There are more secure ways but it depends on setup/needs. But some ex: `chown` to change owner to apache. Or create a group with apache in it and use `chgrp` to change group (may also need o `chmod` to change user and/or group perms too, depending on what you do.  Current perms in OP show read/write only for owner)